# What is the best way for exiting a loop inside an actor?

Tags: akka.net

A rendering actor is drawing a large amount of shapes onto a bitmap. I'd like to stop this process from a supervisor actor
object. Neither `Kill`, nor `Stop` do the job as they wait for the message being handled to finish. To `Ask` an actor from an actor seems to be advised against. What is the right approach in this situation?

Comment: In .Net you normally forward a `CancellationToken` to an async method by parameter. The caller can create its own `CancellationTokenSource` and forward its token. When desired the caller can cancel the token and the callee regulary checks the state of the token to find out if a cancellation is requested.

Comment: @Oliver, thank you for your reply. I haven't thought of running a task from an actor before. For others interested, here's two useful links I've found in the meantime: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40278471/akka-net-how-do-i-stop-an-actor-without-waiting-for-the-current-message-to-finis
https://petabridge.com/blog/top-7-akkadotnet-stumbling-blocks/ (point nr. 4)

Comment: @Oliver pls make this an answer as that is very good hint!

Answer (score 0):

When using an async method, that should be cancelable, you'd normally use a `CancellationToken`. If you already received an cancellation token into your method and you're going to call another async method that should be cancelled by another constraint you can setup your own `CancellationTokenSource`, merge the incoming token into it and forward the new token to the inner function.

If you then need to cancel the inner function, you call the `.Cancel()` method of your token source and your inner function must be polite enough to regulary check the state of the incoming token.

A rough sketch of this approach would be something like this:

```
public async Task DoSomething(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    var tokenSource = CancellationTokenSource.CreateLinkedTokenSource(cancellationToken);
    var token = tokenSource.Token;

    var task = WorkHard(token);
    task.Start();

    await Task.Delay(1000);

    tokenSource.Cancel();
}

private async Task WorkHard(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    while (!cancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Make some hard work");
        await Task.Delay(100);
    }
}
```

A more elaborated example can be found at https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/threading/how-to-listen-for-multiple-cancellation-requests.